# Unknown SSL protocol error when cloning git repository from Gitblit

Tags: git, https, ssh, clone, gitblit

I've set up a git repository that I access over a remote connection. Using the command line, I can clone the repository, do pushes and pulls, etc. by ssh without problems. I'd like to use gitblit to access the repository over a https connection though. Gitblit's web interface shows the repository properly, with all commits, code changes, etc., both from localhost and when using https, but I can't clone from it. Egit simply fails and my terminal gives me the following error:

```
lee@linux-p4b1:~/Downloads/test> git clone https://my-domain.com:8443/git/git_repository
Cloning into git_repository...                             
error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to my-domain.com:8443  while accessing https://my-domain.com:8443/git/git_repository/info/refs   

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Does anybody have a tip as to what could be causing the problem?

Comment: What version of Git are you using?  What version of libcurl do you have installed?  Both have had bugs in the past that affect Git's ability to access http(s) repositories.  Try upgrading them.

Comment: I'm using curl 7.22.0 and git 1.7.7. The libcurl library has the same version number as curl. Is the bug fix known to work after that? I always try to stick as close to the system repositories as I can and those are the newest ones I've got. On the curl website the newest version available for SUSE is 7.24, which isn't that much higher up as far as version numbers are concerned - do you think it'd help?

Comment: Both of those are new enough that they shouldn't have any of the problems I'm familiar with.  But I'm not familiar with this particular problem.

Comment: Hmm... I updated to 7.24 but still get the same error.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm using git version 1.8.1myssgit.1 on Windows and getting the same error.

Comment: To tell the truth, I can't remember. We don't use Gitblit in the company any more. I mostly access the repositories I work with now with ssh. I believe that the problem was probably with the configuration of Gitblit, not git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be related to that openssl bug:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=138168

Comment: Okay... This may be a real newbie question, but would that bug affect me? I found a lot of stuff abou tthe bug before I asked the question but it all seemed to be related to curl. I wasn't aware that git uses curl to access the repository.

Comment: @DanielLee:  Git uses the libcurl library (part of curl) to handle http communications.  Unfortunately, libcurl is quite buggy.

Comment: OP could you add more details on what solved your problem specifically? there are a bunch of different answers on that thread. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues access Stash over https with git. Since libcurl doesn't read .curlrc, I had to patch git to use only ciphers that work. The instructions in this gist are Macports-specific but the patch isn't: https://gist.github.com/jcayzac/9542144